# Setting UImageView and UILabel based on user

Tags: ios

I have a registration for a user in my app. When the user registers they are redirected to a home ViewContoller. I am just wondering how i can set the UIImageView and a label on the home ViewController to the data that the user used when registering. I also am wondering how i can also achieve this when the user logs into the app. Any suggestions would be great:)

Comment: the problem you are facing seems to be very easy but the way you specified is a bit too broad. Maybe some piece of code?

Comment: Hi julian thank you for the reply. I will send code later out from laptop at the moment. I did try this using NSUserFaults but this is mot best way. Also it is worth nothing i am using a Parse database. Would you have any general suggestion to go about achieving this?

Comment: When you get the user data from the server, store it somewhere.  In your home view controller read it in `viewWillLoad` and update your UI as appropriate.  If you have specific problems, open more specific questions and show us the code you have so far.

Comment: `NSUserDefaults` is a fine place to store the info.

Answer (score 0):

First you need what is called a **data model** in software engineering. It contains the basic data structures your app should work with.

In your case, the **data model** would probably contain a class `User`. This `User` class should have **properties**. In your case probably the class would probably look somewhat like that:

```
@interface User : NSObject

@property (strong, nonatomic) NSString *userId;
@property (strong, nonatomic) NSString *name;
@property (strong, nonatomic) UIImage *image;

@end
```

Then in the `viewDidLoad` of your view controller, you need to set the labels which you e.g. can declare as `IBOutlet` from **Interface Builder**, this will look somewhat like that:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
   [super viewDidLoad];
   self.nameLabel = self.user.name; // nameLabel is a UILabel
   self.userIcon.image = self.user.image; // userIcon is a UIImageView
}
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: Thank nburk i will try implement this later!

Comment: i am just curious to how i save the form data into this nsobject properties? e.g when user enters data to lets say form.name and then i need to save this data into the name property in the NSObject.h file?